# Get rsync to report if any local files were updated

Tags: rsync, exit-status

I'm running rsync to do pull from a remote host to the local host.

```
rsync -a --update user@remotehost:/files/ ~/files/
```

I'm running that command from java and using the exit code to work out if it was successful or not.

Is it possible to get that command to report back if any local files were modified? Reporting back via an exit code would be ideal.

Comment: isn't there a colon `':'` missing from the source?

Comment: if you want the remote path to be relative to the remote user's home directory, leave out the slash after the colon.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot get `rsync` to tell you that via the exit code.  The exit codes have documented predefined meanings.

I think the best way to do this from java would be to add the option `--info=NAME` to mention only updated directory and file names:

```
rsync -a --info=NAME --update user@remotehost/files/ ~/files/
```

This prints the names of updated files and directories, one per line, on standard output (fd = 0).

Then you would collect the output from `rsync` and count the number of newlines in the string.

I think a good way to collect the output in `java` can be found in this answer, but I haven't tried it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048519/5484716

Do **not** use `redirectErrorStream` or in any other way merge the standard output an standard error streams.  If you do, you will count error messages as updated files, not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The `--info` flag on `rsync` will output the path of any file transferred.  The exit code of `rsync` indicates success/failure so you wouldn't be able to use it without wrapping a script around the command like

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(rsync -a --info=NAME --update user@remotehost/files/ ~/files/)

if [ $files = "" ]; then
  # files weren't transferred
  exit 0
else
  # files were transferred
  exit 1
fi
```

and then calling that script from java instead of the `rsync` command directly.  `rsync` will probably output some other lines of text at the beginning and end of the transmission so you may need to adjust the `if` statement to account for the extra lines of output but the basic idea would work.

Comment: David, `exit 1` tells the caller that the command failed. `exit 0` tells the caller that the command succeeded.  This script _always_ calls `exit 1` because `rsync -av` _always_ prints output, whether files were transferred or not.

Comment: @RobertL note my comment about adjusting the `if` statement to account for the extra lines of output.  I realize that there will be lines printed even if no files were transferred but the number of lines is depending on version, distro, etc. so I left it up to whoever is actually implementing it to get the number right.

Comment: That's cool. I get it.  I was just pointing out that the script, _as written_, is not functional.  Replace the `v` with ` --info=NAME` and the script works as expected without needing to adjust the `if` statement or otherwise post-process the output of `rsync`.  Thanks for responding!

Comment: @RobertL That's a good point.  So edited.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @DavidKing's idea to let rsync print copied file names, and expanded with information from @yashma that grep will exit nonzero exit status when stdin was empty, we can come up with this satisfyingly short and cryptic one-liner:

```
# prints file list, exits nonzero when that list is empty
rsync -a --info=NAME --update user@remotehost:/files/ ~/files/ | grep .
```

Comment: Don't forget the colon after the hostname.

Comment: @JimL. right on

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the information by return code would be to write a shell script that calls `rsync` and execute the shell script from java. There are some major problems with this as I outline below. The shell script could look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if OUTPUT=$(rsync -a --info=NAME --update user@remotehost/files/ ~/files/)
then
    if [ "$OUTPUT" != "" ]                   # got output?
    then
        exit 0  # yes, success, "some" files were updated
    fi
fi
exit 1  # either rsync failed or no files were updated
```

The main problem with this is that you won't be able to tell if the synchronization process itself completed successfully.  You only know if files were updated or not.  That's why I'd recommend collecting the output in java and count the lines *and* check the return code *in java*.